# How can I make /logout route to /login with method DELETE in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Routes continue to be impenetrable to me. All I want is for the `logout` action to actually log someone out. Here is my attempt:

```
resource :login, controller: "sessions" do
  collection do
    get 'new'
    get 'create'
  end
end

match '/logout', :to => 'login', :controller => "sessions", :action => :destroy, :method => :delete
```

So you see I have this `sessions` controller, and I'm calling it "login". But that makes my link:

```
<%= link_to "Log Out", login_path, :method => :delete %>
```

I have no problem with that EXCEPT I am integrating with an outside site that uses my site as SSO. I need to provide a "logout" link to them. So I want it to just be "logout".

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Geez. I just changed the name from destroy to logout. Please put this as an answer so that I can close it out and award you the points.

Comment: Done and removed the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just make a `logout` action in your session controller and destroy the session there? Then your route can point to session#logout

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

In routes.rb:

```
controller :sessions do
    get 'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
    delete 'logout' => :destroy
end
```

For the logout link:

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', logout_path("current"), method: :delete %>
```